# Hotel room was problematic - what's a typical compensation?

Tags: germany, hotels, compensation

I recently stayed at a hotel in Munich for six days. For three of these days, I couldn't connect to the Internet (they had this problem with their system where you'd get disconnected about 30 seconds after you connected). The room also had a foul smell which, as it got stronger, I traced to the bathroom drain; I was moved out of my room into another room, which was smaller, plus I had to move myself. I'll also mention that I had asked them for cables to connect my laptop to the monitor and the room, and they didn't have those.

It's not a fancy hotel, but not a cheap hostel either. The nightly price was 91 EUR, including a very nice breakfast.

When I checked out, I complained about the first two problems - although perhaps not very assertively. What I was offered was a discount equivalent to the price  of a soft drink I had taken from the mini-bar. Since I was in a hurry to catch a train, I did not argue - but I do feel I got short-changed and I should have demanded more; say, one of the days off.

My question is: Is there a customary rate or level of compensation in such cases? And if so, is it at the level of a mini-bar drink, a meal at the hotel restaurant, a free night's stay, or more?

I'll mention that the lack of Internet access was an issue for me, since I was attending a conference and need to access resources on-line before and after each day.

Comment: I am not sure there is any good answer to this question. Sure you can always insist, but I don't think you have any specific rights or any reason think it would be successful. The foul smell is certainly a problem but a free drink at the bar for a minor issue like switching rooms is par for the course, even at more expensive hotels. Internet problems are annoying but quite common, often down to third-parties and not something hotels typically take as their responsibility. And a cable to connect your own equipment isn't even a reasonable request to begin with, certainly not at a cheap hotel!

Comment: For €91 with a nice breakfast is really cheap for a city like Munich. At the end of the day, they solved the Internet problem, they switched the room and they made a gesture, I don't think you ought to feel shortchanged. But that's all that can be said and ultimately a matter of opinion, which is why I don't think the question is very good.

Comment: @Relaxed: See edit. I'm now asking about what's customary. Also, if I insisted - I would essentially not be paying them and it would be up to them to demand I pay, so it could devolve into a legal argument.

Comment: OK, fair enough.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Please consider reopening following the edit.

Comment: It depends on the hotel, e.g. Radisson Blu has a 100% satisfaction guarantee policy where you don't pay anything if the there are problems during your stay that could not be addressed.

Answer (score 9):

No, there is no customary rate but you may be expecting a bit much...

> you'd get disconnected about 30 seconds after you connected

Did you confirm this with other attendees or guests?  What did the ISP support line say?

> The room also had a foul smell...I was moved out of my room into another room

This is the expected outcome.

> which was smaller,

How much smaller?  Room sizes do vary within the same category.  Next time, ask if the smaller room has a lower rack rate.  If so, you can use that to justify an adjustment.

> I had to move myself.

This is perfectly normal.

> I had asked them for cables to connect my laptop to the monitor and the room, and they didn't have those.

That is outside any reasonable expectation, however, if you ask to see the lost wire box, you may find what you need, along assorted chargers and what not.

As this point, it's over.  They made an offer and you accepted it.  Next time, don't wait until the end.  If you are a member of their loyalty program, 100 EUR worth of points is about right.

Comment: "Did you confirm etc" - Yes, there was a hotel-wide problem. The reception people actually complained to me about how other guests were very angry and bothersome about this. It happened on a Friday and they only fixed it by Tuesday.

Comment: Also, there's nothing normal nor expected about plumbing problems, getting sewage smell in your room, nor about moving yourself from room to room for no fault of your own and without the hotel staff's help. Anyway, your answer seems mostly like a personal opinion + a comment IMO.

Comment: @einpoklum For clarity, moving to another room is the expected outcome, not the plumbing problem.  Was the hotel even equipped to assist in the move?  Meaning they have Bell staff?  Did you ask for a Bellman?  You're free to ignore the Answer, but it is 95% applicable from experience, work history and study so...